# Django Encoding Issues with MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, encoding

Okay, so I have a MySQL database set up. Most of the tables are latin1 and Django handles them fine. But, some of them are UTF-8 and Django does not handle them.

Here's a sample table (these tables are all from django-geonames):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `geoname`;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
CREATE TABLE `geoname` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ascii_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(20,17) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(20,17) NOT NULL,
  `point` point default NULL,
  `fclass` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `fcode` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `cc2` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `admin1_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `admin2_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `admin3_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `admin4_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `population` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `elevation` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gtopo30` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timezone_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `moddate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `country_id_refs_iso_alpha2_e2614807` (`country_id`),
  KEY `admin1_id_refs_id_a28cd057` (`admin1_id`),
  KEY `admin2_id_refs_id_4f9a0f7e` (`admin2_id`),
  KEY `admin3_id_refs_id_f8a5e181` (`admin3_id`),
  KEY `admin4_id_refs_id_9cc00ec8` (`admin4_id`),
  KEY `fcode_refs_code_977fe2ec` (`fcode`),
  KEY `timezone_id_refs_id_5b46c585` (`timezone_id`),
  KEY `geoname_52094d6e` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

Now, if I try to get data from the table directly using MySQLdb and a cursor, I get the text with the proper encoding:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> 
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
... user = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER'],
... passwd = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'],
... db = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'])
>>> cursor = conn.cursor ()
>>> cursor.execute("select name from geoname where name like 'Uni%Hidalgo'");
1L
>>> g = cursor.fetchone()
>>> g[0]
'Uni\xc3\xb3n Hidalgo'
>>> print g[0]
Unión Hidalgo
```

However, if I try to use the Geoname model (which is actually a `django.contrib.gis.db.models.Model`), it fails:

```
>>> from geonames.models import Geoname
>>> g = Geoname.objects.get(name__istartswith='Uni',name__icontains='Hidalgo')
>>> g.name
u'Uni\xc3\xb3n Hidalgo'
>>> print g.name
UniÃ³n Hidalgo
```

There's pretty clearly an encoding error here. In both cases the database is returning 'Uni\xc3\xb3n Hidalgo' but Django is (incorrectly?) translating the '\xc3\xb3n' to Ã³.

What can I do to fix this?

## Update

Okay, so this is weird:

```
>>> c = unicode('Uni\xc3\xb3n Hidalgo','utf-8')
>>> c
u'Uni\xf3n Hidalgo'
>>> print c
Unión Hidalgo
```

If I *force* python to encode the string into Unicode from utf-8, it works. However, this recreates the mistake:

```
>>> c = unicode('Unión Hidalgo','latin1')
>>> c
u'Uni\xc3\xb3n Hidalgo'
>>> print c
UniÃ³n Hidalgo
```

So, my guess MySQL is sending utf-8 but telling Python it is latin1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in MySQL after all. I dropped the tables, recreated them with charset and collate set to UTF, and re-imported all of the data.

It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

you could use like this

```
>>> print g.name.encode('latin1')
Unión Hidalgo
```

Comment: I seriously can't do this everywhere I need this value. Is there something I can do to either MySQL or Django to get them to behave?

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.10, MariaDB 5.5.47

---

A very important thing is set the database's character set when you create database:

```
CREATE DATABASE `my_database` CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Then you can check your mysql's configure files `/etc/my.cnf`(I use MariaDB):

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
```

Also remember to restart your sqlservice:

```
sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service
```

ref:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#creating-your-database
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/setting-character-sets-and-collations/